# Navbar hoover transition mouseover issue

Tags: css, navbar, transition

I have done transition on hover (when I hover on navbar width is bigger and main content moves a bit on right site). However unfortunately main content moves on page refresh which I would like to avoid. Any idea how to code: mouseover transition back effect?

```
.navbar:hover+main {
    margin-left: 10rem;
}

.navbar + main {
    transition: 1s;
}
```

It does work properly on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47d5ujym/
Unfortunately does not work properly with Opera, Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Hey im pretty sure I wrote this code! :D Could you add the rest of your code?

Comment: What if you change it to `transition: margin 1s;` if that doesn't work I'll need the rest of the code

Comment: Yes you did but you did not replied on previous topic. Unfortunately transition starts on every page refresh which is not helping me :(

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the fiddle you provided it seems to work, I think you add margin to the `main` somewhere in your code and that will transition it but the fiddle you sent works

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```css
.navbar:hover+main {
    margin-left: 10rem;
}

.navbar + main {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still the same